# How to generate a list of random values excluding values in another list

Tags: python-3.x

I am using **Python 3.6.3**.

My code generates a random list of five values (type integer).

The values in this random list are compared to another list, which contains values to exclude from the generated list. That means, if a random number is mentioned in the excluded_numbers list, a redraw must be processed to obtain a new value.

Below is a simplified source code : (you can copy/paste, this code is running)

```
import numpy as np
import random

excluded_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,15,18,30] # values to exclude from the random list


print ("draw_numbers to exclude    ",excluded_values,"\n")
loops = 1

for ln in range (0,loops):
#   Random list
    z=[]
    z=random.sample(range(1,30), 5)  # no duplicates
    z.sort()
    print ("Draw numbers original list   z   ", z,"\n")
# Standard deviation draw_numbers
    deviation = np.std(z)
    deviation=float(deviation)
    deviation= round (deviation,5)
    print ("draw_numbers  loop number ",ln,"  ", z, "   standard deviation    ", deviation,"\n")
    control_list = []
    for i in range (0,5):
               
        draw_number = z[i]
        draw_number = str(draw_number)
        print ("Draw number   z[",i,"]     ",draw_number)             
        print ("Original random list z   ",z)
               
        if int(draw_number) in excluded_values:  
            print ("Present in excluded_values")
# trigger if draw_number must be excluded
            draw_number= random.randint(1,50)
            print ("------>>>  REDRAW draw_number    ", draw_number)
            draw_number = int (draw_number)
            control_list.append(draw_number)
            print ("Control list   ", control_list,"   Original list  z  ",z,"\n")
        else:
            draw_number = int (draw_number)
            control_list.append(draw_number)
            print ("Control list   ", control_list,"     z  ",z,"\n")
        continue
        z = control_list 
    continue
```

But a problem is still remaining.

When a redraw occcurs, the new draw number must be checked against excluded_values list, **AND** **control_list**, in order to get a final control_ list completely clean with no duplicates.

I did not find how to arrange this double process after trying many ways in my code; I missed maybe an argument or method, and I dont know how to manage this "circular" process.

Below is an example of running the code above:

```
draw_numbers to exclude     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 15, 18, 30] 

Draw numbers original list   z    [4, 6, 9, 12, 18] 

draw_numbers  loop number  0    [4, 6, 9, 12, 18]    standard deviation     4.91528 

Draw number   z[ 0 ]      4
Original random list z    [4, 6, 9, 12, 18]
 Present in excluded_values
------>>>  REDRAW draw_number     45
Control list    [45]    Original list  z   [4, 6, 9, 12, 18] 

Draw number   z[ 1 ]      6
Original random list z    [4, 6, 9, 12, 18]
 Present in excluded_values
------>>>  REDRAW draw_number     40
Control list    [45, 40]    Original list  z   [4, 6, 9, 12, 18] 

Draw number   z[ 2 ]      9
Original random list z    [4, 6, 9, 12, 18]
Control list    [45, 40, 9]      z   [4, 6, 9, 12, 18] 

Draw number   z[ 3 ]      12
Original random list z    [4, 6, 9, 12, 18]
Control list    [45, 40, 9, 12]      z   [4, 6, 9, 12, 18] 

Draw number   z[ 4 ]      18
Original random list z    [4, 6, 9, 12, 18]
 Present in excluded_values
------>>>  REDRAW draw_number     14
Control list    [45, 40, 9, 12, 14]    Original list  z   [4, 6, 9, 12, 18]
```

Thank you for your help and your time.

Anyway, take care and stay safe @ home.

Greetings from Paris, France :)

Comment: isn't it simpler to just draw numbers from a set of numbers that does not have the excluded numbers?

Comment: Chavoua Tov ! :)  Not really, because in my code the excluded_values list is fixed for commodity reasons (I do not have to input the list manually in the console). The excluded values can be changed via input at every run. The final program is intended to generate hundreds  of lists, written then in an Excel file via xslxwriter module for further process (already developed)

Comment: still, you have all_lst and excl_lst both can be dynamic and change from input. you can just draw from the set(all_lst)-set(excl_lst). No?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question (I am not yet expert in Python). Random function is mandatory. Regarding my code above, is there a fine and easy solution?

Comment: To be more clear, excluded values are an input at the beginning of run, and draw lists are generated via random function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments, here is a simpler solution

```
from random import sample

k = 5
all_values = range(30)
excluded_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,15,18,30]

k_sampled = sample(set(all_values) - set(excluded_values), k)
print(k_sampled) # --> [28, 10, 8, 11, 20]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lior Cohen, it runs perfect. I was very far from this solution. I will adapt my main code very soon, following your precious advice ! Thanks again ! I don't want to be indiscrete, where are you from ?  :)

Comment: Sorry , I just did click. Is it OK for you?

Comment: To attention to Lior Cohen, I confirm that I inserted your solution in my main code, and It is working fast and perfectly. Thanks again !  This question can be closed now. Is it automatic? Cheers

Comment: glad to hear. no need to close.